# How to map SQL_VARIANT in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity framework 6 database first. There was already designed database and I need to use it to create an API.
In severl tables [sql_variant] was used as a column type.
When I added entity framework, all [sql_variant] columns were ignored with warning informing me that there is no mapping for this type!

I tried to manually add the [sql_variant] column with object type and map it. But I'm getting its value always null!

```
//The name of my [sql_variant] column is Value.
[Column("Value", TypeName = "sql_variant")]
[Required]
public object Value { get; set; }


//In the context class I tried to add also the following.
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
 modelBuilder.Entity<MeasurementData>();
 modelBuilder.Properties<MeasurementData>();
}
```

I'm still getting the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The specified type member 'Value' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Comment: Note:
I know that it's not recommended to use SQL_VARIANT, but in my case, I have to deal with that!

Comment: SQL_VARIANT is not only not recommended in EF6, but not supported. afaik, it became supported in EF Core 2.1, but before that, the suggested workaround is the use of stored procedures.

Comment: Other options might be to hide it behind a `view` or use SQL script directly from EF.

Comment: I tried to use SQL script with "SqlQuery" and I'm also getting null values
@PeterSmith

Comment: @DevilSuichiro
So there is no way to force mapping it with new added property of type "object"?

Comment: @Firas I don't know of any. I read of some attempts to map it as a complex type, which would allow reading it, but not querying on it or writing to it from attached entities.

Comment: Visit this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql-variant-in-Entity-Framework. Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: @Tomato32 this is the attempt I was mentioning. As you can read in the limitations in the bottom: '•Since this implementation provides only a read access to sql_variant columns, you can neither write to these columns, nor run DB queries against their values. '

Comment: This article was written 8 Jan 2011 I came across it, but I said that from that time on, there should be a new way or something presented by Microsoft itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same requirement. The table that I have has a single sql_variant field. What I did was I mapped the sql_variant column to an int C# field using the knowledge that the criteria I use to query some specific data in this table returns int values in the sql_variant column.

Let's say the table is called EntityPropertyValue with a sql_variant column called PropertyValue.

Then you can have several EF C# classes, EntityIntPropertyValue, EntityStringPropertyValue etc. where PropertyValue in EntityIntPropertyValue is declared:

```
[Column("PropertyValue")]
public int PropertyValue {get; set;}
```

In EntityStringPropertyValue, you have:

```
[Column("PropertyValue")]
public String PropertyValue {get; set;}
```

The where clauses I use in the code do not reference this field. I expect that if you do reference the field in your code, the sql statement generated by EF might fail during conversions due to invalid conversions especially varchar -> int. I haven't tried it.

I know, it is a bit of more work but it works in my context. Inserting rows and populating the column with int values works.